# The reply address 'https://...' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application even though the address exists

Tags: azure, adal

Trying to get some more clarity on the Azure AD app registration. I have two Reply URLs:

https://example.com
https://example.com/

I'm getting the infamous reply address mismatch, one with the trailing slash and the other without.

My understanding of this was that the app would check ALL redirect URLs to see if there was a match versus just one and failing. I've seen numerous Microsoft articles with multiple domains or routes on the same entry. Why does this fail? I also noticed this morning that my first entry in the list had the slash, and when I added the one without, it automatically moved it to the top - which I thought was odd.

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Can you add the redirect URI as it is specified in your redirect query parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Reply URLs in your code? Before I also encountered the replay address mismatch problem, I found the Reply URLs missed the trailing slash in the code to result in this mismatch, and same time there was no the trailing slash in the Azure portal.